# C# prepare connection string for server

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, connection-string

I'm about to send my Visual Studio project (C#, ASP.NET) and database (MS Access) to someone who will upload it into a server (don't know which one).

However, given that database file will be at the same map with the project, how do I prepare my connection string for that database? So far I worked local at my computer, including the database.

This is how my connection looks like in `web.config`, what changes do I need to make?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Project\etc\DATABASE.mdb"
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString1" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DATABASE.mdb"
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could ask him to create the mdb file in a folder relative to the project and then give a relative project in the web.config

Comment: If the mdb file will always be in the same map as the project you can build the connectionstring in code and forget the web.config ever existed

Comment: @GuidoG I see, as Im very bad with connection-strings, how do I tell the project to read "Database.mdb" in same root map?

Comment: there are lots of examples on how to construct a connectionstring in c# if you search it in google, it depends on what database and what components you are using

Comment: @GuidoG The guy said I could put the database with the projects file, meaning location "\Database.mdb' should be enough. However I'm getting error "`Could not find file 'C:\Database.mdb'.`. How do I make the project look into it's own path instead from C: drive?

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

Comment: it depends on how you handle your connection object. Maybe if you show us your code on how the connection is created and used we might help you with this

Comment: @GuidoG Thank you, I manage to fix it however by setting it to `Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database.mdb"`. I had to put it in App_Data folder for doing so, since it couldn't read at "first level" or whatever it's called.